# Plotting line chart with different colours for pos and neg values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a line chart with different colours for positive and negative values. 
Unfortunately the plotting is somehow bugy. A few values next to 0 are displayed in the wrong colour.

[image]

the code:

```
set.seed(345); df2 <- data.frame(date=1:100, y=cumsum(runif(100)-0.5))
d <- ggplot2::ggplot( df2, ggplot2::aes(date, y) ) +
   ggplot2::geom_line( ggplot2::aes( group = 1, color= (y < 0)));d
```

Any ideas why the plotting isn't working?

Comment: The color here is based on the value at the beginning of each segment. To get different colors for all negative values vs. positive values, you'd need to interpolate your data to have a point at each crossing.

Comment: use `approx` to interpolate

Answer (score 1):

`geom_line()` will color from the current point to the next point using the current point's value. I hope this chart helps to explain:

```
set.seed(345)

df2 <- 
  data.frame(
    date = 1:100, 
    y = cumsum(runif(100) - 0.5)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(line_color = y < 0) 

ggplot(slice(df2, 60:85), aes(date, y, color = line_color)) +
  geom_segment(
    aes(
      x = (date), xend = lead(date), 
      y = (y), yend = lead(y)
    ), 
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.15, "inches"), ends = "first"),
    size = 1
  ) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

[image]

You can use `lead()` and `lag()` logic to determine the colors that you want ahead of time. This example will color anything that goes to or from a value < 0. Even though that point around 80 is above zero, the line remains teal becuase the points before and after it are less than zero.

```
df2 %>% 
mutate(line_color =  y < 0 | lead(y, default = first(y)) < 0) %>%
ggplot(aes(date, y, color = line_color)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = 1)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = y < 0), size = 3) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

[image]