# Create a line chart in ggplot with the lines taking different colors depending on percentage changes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a time series data that I would like to inspect visually using `ggplot` using `geom_line`. I would like to see whether the segments of the line has increased or decreased with respect to the previous time period based on the color being displayed (for example red for decrease and green for increase), similar to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972248/plotting-line-chart-with-different-colours-for-pos-and-neg-values).

As a second step, I would like add points to the figure only when there was a change in trend.

For example, using the internal R dataset called `economics`, I can prepare the data like so:

```
library(tidyverse)

t <- economics %>%
  filter(date >= "2013-09-01") %>%
  mutate(pct_change = (uempmed/lag(uempmed) - 1) * 100 ,
         line_color =  pct_change < 0)
```

The percentage change gives:

```
 [1]          NA  -1.2121212   4.9079755   1.1695906 -10.9826590   3.2467532  -0.6289308  -0.6329114
 [9]  -7.0063694  -5.4794521  -5.0724638  -1.5267176   3.8759690   1.4925373  -4.4117647  -0.7692308
[17]   2.3255814  -2.2727273  -6.9767442  -4.1666667
```

I have tried using this:

```
  ggplot(data = na.omit(t) , aes(x = date, y = uempmed)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = 1 ,color = line_color )) + 
  geom_point(shape = 1 )
```

But it doesn't give me what I am looking for:

[image]

The colors are wrong, and there are points appearing everywhere.

My question has two parts;

1. How can I code this so that the line representing uempmed appears green when when it is increasing, red when it is decreasing, and
2. add a `geom_point` only when uempmed has switched from increasing to decreasing and vice versa

I am grateful for any help.

Edit for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the right colors for your lines compute the percentage change based on the `lead`, i.e. the line is colored based on the "starting" value. And to add points only when a change in the sign occurs add an indicator variable to your dataset by comparing the sign of `pct_change` and its `lag` value. Afterwards you can filter the dataset based on this indicator variable for `geom_point`. Additonally, instead of removing rows with NAs I used `replace_na` to assign a value for `line_color` and `sign_change`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

t <- economics %>%
  filter(date >= "2013-09-01") %>%
  mutate(
    pct_change = (uempmed / lead(uempmed) - 1) * 100,
    line_color = pct_change < 0,
    sign_change = sign(pct_change) * sign(lag(pct_change))
  ) %>%
  replace_na(list(line_color = FALSE, sign_change = 0))

ggplot(data = t, aes(x = date, y = uempmed)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = 1, color = line_color)) +
  geom_point(data = ~filter(.x, sign_change < 0), shape = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how we can do it:

1. I removed the NA
2. Created a logical vector `sign_switch` for the points
3. wrapped the color aesthetics within an `ifelse`
4. Tweaked a little for fine looking

```
library(tidyverse)

t <- economics %>%
  filter(date >= "2013-09-01") %>%
  mutate(pct_change = (uempmed/lag(uempmed) - 1) * 100 ,
         line_color =  pct_change < 0) %>% 
  drop_na(pct_change) %>% 
  mutate(sign_switch = sign(pct_change) != sign(lag(pct_change))) 
  
ggplot(t, aes(x = date, y = pct_change, group = 1))+
  geom_line(aes(color = ifelse(pct_change < 0, "green", "red"))) +
  labs(color = "")+
  geom_point(data = filter(t, sign_switch & !is.na(sign_switch)), size = 3, color = "red") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c( "green", "red"))+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it possible to plot variable uempmed using your technique? My intention is to plot uempmed throughout time and not the percentage change i.e. if uempmed is increasing then the lin is green, otherwise red. The percentage change is there to help the calculation. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: Just replace y=pct_change with y=uemped!